# Type errors with Existential types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeerror, typechecking, existential-type, zipper

I am struggling with existential types in my program. I think I'm trying to do something very reasonable however I cannot get past the typechecker :(

I have a datatype that sort of mimics a Monad

```
data M o = R o | forall o1. B (o1 -> M o) (M o1)
```

Now I create a Context for it, similar to that described in [Haskell Wiki article on Zipper](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper), however I use a function instead of a data structure for simplicity -

```
type C o1 o2 = M o1 -> M o2
```

Now when I try to write a function that splits a data value into its context and subvalue, the typechecker complains -

```
ctx :: M o -> (M o1 -> M o, M o1)
ctx (B f m) = (B f, m) -- Doesn't typecheck
```

Error is -

```
Couldn't match type `o2' with `o1'
  `o2' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         B :: forall o o1. (o1 -> M o) -> M o1 -> M o,
       in an equation for `ctx'
       at delme1.hs:6:6
  `o1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for ctx :: M o -> (M o1 -> M o, M o1)
       at delme1.hs:6:1
Expected type: M o2
  Actual type: M o1
In the expression: m
In the expression: (B f, m)
```

However, I can work around it like so -

```
ctx (B f m) = let (c,m') = ctx m in ((B f) . c, m') -- OK
```

Why does this second definition typecheck but not the first one?

Also, if I try to convert `ctx` to a complete function by checking for R, I again get a typecheck error -

```
ctx (R o) = (id, R o) -- Doesn't typecheck
```

Error -

```
Couldn't match type `o' with `o1'
  `o' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for ctx :: M o -> (M o1 -> M o, M o1)
      at delme1.hs:7:1
  `o1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for ctx :: M o -> (M o1 -> M o, M o1)
       at delme1.hs:7:1
In the first argument of `R', namely `o'
In the expression: R o
In the expression: (id, R o)
```

How can I work around this error?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the failing cases first. Both of these fail for the same reason, which is clearer once you add in the implicit `forall` in the type signature:

```
ctx :: forall o o1. M o -> (M o1 -> M o, M o1)
```

i.e. your function must not only work for a some `o1`, but for *any* `o1`.

1. In your first case,

   ```
   ctx (B f m) = (B f, m)
   ```

   we know that `f :: (o2 -> M o)` and `m :: M o2`, for *some* type `o2`, but we have to be able to offer *any* type `o1`, so we can't assume that `o1 ~ o2`.
2. In the second case,

   ```
   ctx (R o) = (id, R o)
   ```

   Here, we know that `o :: o`, but again, the function has to be defined for *any* `o1`, so we can't assume that `o ~ o1`.

Your workaround only seems to work because it's calling itself, similar to an inductive proof. But without a base case, it's just circular reasoning, and you cannot write the base case for this function, because there is no way to construct an `M o1` from an `M o` for any combination of `o` and `o1` without using a bottom value.

What you'll probably need to do, is to define another existential type for the context, instead of using just a tuple. Not sure if it'll work for your needs, but this compiles<sup>1</sup>, at least:

```
data Ctx o = forall o1. Ctx (M o1 -> M o) (M o1)

ctx :: M o -> Ctx o
ctx (B f m) = case ctx m of Ctx c m' -> Ctx (B f . c) m'
ctx (R o)   = Ctx id (R o)
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Try using a `let` instead of `case` for [a funny GHC error](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1955624#1955624) :)</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Using an existential type instead of a Tuple worked handsomely, and I learnt a lot in the process!